# Beta Testing Android Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Apparently, by mistake published me app on the play store before putting out a beta. I created a google group, and invited all my testers. However, they still see version 1.0 on the play store and not version 1.1?

Is there a problem? or does it take longer to show up? and how will the user know it is the beta app other than the version number?

Comment: It takes some time for the app to show up on Play Store!

Comment: gotcha, the reason i am doing this is because i compiled an app and installed fine on my phone, however when i uploaded to the playstore, and download it from there, it crashes.

Comment: This seems like something best addressed to them!?!

Answer (score 0):

your testers has to go to following link and become a tester

```
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/<Your_Package_ID>
```

And they will see new updates as soon as Google update its database (it usually is taking 12h) but if you already added them to group and added group into your app then should not be any delay to seeing your new version.